# How to save command output to variable

Tags: variables, tcl, expect

i'm writing a script in expect and want to save the output of an command in a variable. Is that possible?
The command is

```
echo "text here"| base64
```

i know i can set a variable with "set" but

```
set var ["echo text here| base64"]
```

or

```
set var [ spawn "echo text here| base64"]
```

doesn't work. With that i'm just saving the string not the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `exec` command returns the output from a command. That lets you set it into a variable:

```
set var [exec echo "text here" | base64]
```

However, you can avoid the `echo`:

```
set var [exec base64 << "text here"]
```

And in Tcl 8.6 you can completely skip running an external program:

```
set var [binary encode base64 "text here"]
```

There's also [a base64 encoder in Tcllib](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/base64/base64.md):

```
package require base64
set var [base64::encode "text here"]
```